# Filter System processes from user processes

Tags: c++, handle

I need to know how can I filter current user files/processes from operating system processes ? 
I have listed all the current running files through the attached code in C++ .
now, i need to know how can i show only user files from this list?

Is there any demarcation parameter for this!!

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>

//  Forward declarations:
BOOL GetProcessList( );
BOOL ListProcessModules( DWORD dwPID );
void printError( TCHAR* msg );

int main( void )
{
  GetProcessList( );
  return 0;
}

BOOL GetProcessList( )
{
  HANDLE hProcessSnap;
  HANDLE hProcess;
  PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;


  // Take a snapshot of all processes in the system.
  hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );
  if( hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
  {
    printError( TEXT("CreateToolhelp32Snapshot (of processes)") );
    return( FALSE );
  }

  // Set the size of the structure before using it.
  pe32.dwSize = sizeof( PROCESSENTRY32 );

  // Retrieve information about the first process,
  // and exit if unsuccessful
  if( !Process32First( hProcessSnap, &pe32 ) )
  {
    printError( TEXT("Process32First") ); // show cause of failure
    CloseHandle( hProcessSnap );          // clean the snapshot object
    return( FALSE );
  }

  // Now walk the snapshot of processes, and
  // display information about each process in turn
  do
  {
    _tprintf( TEXT("\n\n=====================================================" ));
    _tprintf( TEXT("\nPROCESS NAME:  %s"), pe32.szExeFile );


    // List the modules and threads associated with this process
    ListProcessModules( pe32.th32ProcessID );

  } while( Process32Next( hProcessSnap, &pe32 ) );

  CloseHandle( hProcessSnap );
  return( TRUE );
}


BOOL ListProcessModules( DWORD dwPID )
{
  HANDLE hModuleSnap = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
  MODULEENTRY32 me32;

  // Take a snapshot of all modules in the specified process.
  hModuleSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, dwPID );
  if( hModuleSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
  {
    printError( TEXT("CreateToolhelp32Snapshot (of modules)") );
    return( FALSE );
  }

  // Set the size of the structure before using it.
  me32.dwSize = sizeof( MODULEENTRY32 );

  // Retrieve information about the first module,
  // and exit if unsuccessful
  if( !Module32First( hModuleSnap, &me32 ) )
  {
    printError( TEXT("Module32First") );  // show cause of failure
    CloseHandle( hModuleSnap );           // clean the snapshot object
    return( FALSE );
  }

  // Now walk the module list of the process,
  // and display information about each module
  do
  {
    _tprintf( TEXT("\n\n     MODULE NAME:     %s"),   me32.szModule );
    _tprintf( TEXT("\n     Executable     = %s"),     me32.szExePath );

  } while( Module32Next( hModuleSnap, &me32 ) );

  CloseHandle( hModuleSnap );
  return( TRUE );
}


void printError( TCHAR* msg )
{
  DWORD eNum;
  TCHAR sysMsg[256];
  TCHAR* p;

  eNum = GetLastError( );
  FormatMessage( FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
         NULL, eNum,
         MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), // Default language
         sysMsg, 256, NULL );

  // Trim the end of the line and terminate it with a null
  p = sysMsg;
  while( ( *p > 31 ) || ( *p == 9 ) )
    ++p;
  do { *p-- = 0; } while( ( p >= sysMsg ) &&
                          ( ( *p == '.' ) || ( *p < 33 ) ) );

  // Display the message
  _tprintf( TEXT("\n  WARNING: %s failed with error %d (%s)"), msg, eNum, sysMsg );
}
```

Comment: Maybe something like this?

`if((GetFileAttributes(/*file*/) & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM) == 0)
{
  /*not a system file*/
}
`
Dunno, I'm only guessing.

Comment: Thnkyou for the input but it's not working... 
Adding this clause doesn't show any opened up file- neither system nor user !!